# Can't get @override annotation from method

Tags: java, annotations

When I get method from `class` instance, and want to get `@override` annotation.
but method has not any annotation.
Is it impossible to get `@override`  annotation?

code is below.

```
package com.test;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

public class ReflectionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ChildHoge childHoge = new ChildHoge();
        Method method = childHoge.getClass().getMethod("init");
        for (Annotation s : method.getAnnotations()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        Method method2 = childHoge.getClass().getMethod("a");
        for (Annotation a : method2.getAnnotations()) {
            System.out.println(a); // =>@javax.annotation.Resource(mappedName=, shareable=true, type=class java.lang.Object, authenticationType=CONTAINER, lookup=, description=, name=)

        }
    }

}

class SuperHoge {
    public void init() {

    }
}


class ChildHoge extends SuperHoge {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();
    }
    @Resource
    public void a() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Override {
}
```

It has `RetentionPolicy.SOURCE` which are discarded by the compiler, which means it cannot be obtained at runtime. You can see this described in [JLS 9.6.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.2).

> If an annotation a corresponds to a type T, and T has a
>   (meta-)annotation m that corresponds to
>   `java.lang.annotation.Retention`, then:
>
> - If m has an element whose value is
>     `java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.SOURCE`, then a Java compiler must
>     ensure that a is not present in the binary representation of the class
>     or interface in which a appears.

And the Javadoc for `RetentionPolicy` also describes this:

```
public enum RetentionPolicy {
    /**
     * Annotations are to be discarded by the compiler.
     */
    SOURCE,
    ...
```

Comment: So: No. It cannot be obtained from the class file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Reflection API to check if the method is overridden or not
e.g.

```
class.getMethod("myMethod").getDeclaringClass();
```

If the class that's returned is your own, then it's not overridden; if it's something else, that subclass has overridden it.